# use one testclass function to another testclass in python

Tags: python, django

I have two test classes in django testcases . i want to use one testclass function to another testclass in python.
django testcases for restframework:

```
class TestExample(APITestCase):
   def test_ex(self):
      print "test_ex"

class TestSample(APITestCase):
    def test_sample(self):
        print "test_sample"
```

how can use `test_ex function` in `test_sample` function

Answer (score 0):

one approach is inheritance

```
class TestExample(APITestCase):
  def test_ex(self):
  print "test_ex"

class TestSample(TestExample):
   def test_sample(self):
     print "test_sample"
```

Comment: I have tried with inheritance but if there is 5 test functions in TestExample if i use inheritance .and if i run all test use command python manage.py test app.tests                    then it will run all tests from Inherited Class again after run second class test

Comment: @satyavanapalli inheritance is the solution indeed, but using multiple inheritance to avoid this issue, cf my answer.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers as he mention

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to use multiple inheritance: you first write a mixin class (deriving from object) with the code you want to share between testcases, then your testcases that inherit from both `Unittest.TestCase` (or a subclass of) and your mixin:

```
class ExampleTestMixin(object):
   def test_ex(self):
      print "test_ex"


class TestExample(APITestCase, ExampleTestMixin):
    def test_something_else(self):
        print "test something else"


class TestSample(APITestCase, ExampleTestMixin):
    def test_sample(self):
        print "test_sample"
```